# How to play Audio when iOS device connected to Airpods swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

`let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

```
do {
  // audio session setup
  try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: [.allowAirPlay,.allowBluetoothA2DP])
  try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
  try session.setActive(true)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to integrate this snippet , it worked to me :

```
[AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetoothA2DP]
```

Hope it will work.